# angular start (ReferenceError: angular is not defined)

Tags: java, angularjs, dependency-injection, declaration, angularjs-routing

I am trying build frontend in my aplication ( java-ee ) using angularJS. I can't inject angular application to my jsp file. I have always this error: `ReferenceError: angular is not defined`. I knew that it is easy error but I can't find solution. Below there are my code:

index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html>

    <head>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/registration/registration.module.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/registration/RegistrationCtrl.js" />"></script>

        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular/angular.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js" />"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="frontendApp">
        <div ng-view></></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';
/**
 * 
 */

angular.module('frontendApp', ['ngRoute', 'registrationControllers'])
    .config([ '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/rest',{
        templateUrl: 'resources/angular-app/registration/registration.html',
        controller: 'RegistrationCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

controller:

```
'use strict';
/**
 * 
 */

var registrationControllers = angular.module('frontendApp', []);

registrationControllers.controller('RegistrationCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change script references like below.

```
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular/angular.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js" />"></script>

        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/registration/registration.module.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/registration/RegistrationCtrl.js" />"></script>
```

You were overriding your `frontendApp` inside the controller.js
That was clearing your whole `frontendApp`. You should always declared module once with dependency and then reuse it by that module name only.

```
'use strict';

var frontendApp = angular.module('frontendApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config([ '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/rest',{
        templateUrl: 'resources/angular-app/registration/registration.html',
        controller: 'RegistrationCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

frontendApp.controller('RegistrationCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  }]);
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how registration.module.js can see RegistrationCtrl so it is inject below...

Comment: you need to load registration.module.js before controller.js thats why the `frontendApp` variable defines first and available for other javascript files

Comment: Thant you for help. I changed order links and those errors disapperared but still does't load registration.html. Do you knew why ? Sory for my english and angular knowledge :P :)

Comment: is there any error in console? have you tried my code?

Comment: No, console in firebug is clear, any errors. Yes, I copy your code :) Path templateUrl is good

Comment: can you please tell me the version of angularjs and angularjs routing?

Answer (score 1):

re-arrang your scripts

```
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/registration/registration.module.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/registration/RegistrationCtrl.js" />"></script>

        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular/angular.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js" />"></script>
```

to be

```
                <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" />"></script>
                <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular/angular.js" />"></script>
                <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" />"></script>
                <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" />"></script>
                <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js" />"></script>

                <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/registration/registration.module.js" />"></script>
                <script src="<c:url value="/resources/angular-app/registration/RegistrationCtrl.js" />"></script>
```

why you defining another module in the controller???